# Build createCriteria in Grails dynamically and in a DRY way?

Tags: grails, groovy, createcriteria

I'm working on building a `createCriteria` dynamically.  So far, so good:

`obj` is the domain object(s) I want back
`rulesList` is a list of maps which hold the field to be searched on, the operator to use, and the value to search against

```
def c = obj.createCriteria()
l = c.list (max: irows, offset: offset) {
    switch(obj){           //constrain results to those relevant to the user
        case Vehicle:
            eq("garage", usersGarage)
            break
        case Garage:
            users {
                idEq(user.id)
            }
            break
    }
    rulesList.each { rule ->
        switch(rule['op']){
            case 'eq':
                eq("${rule['field']}", rule['value'])
                break
            case 'ne':
                ne("${rule['field']}", rule['value'])
                break
            case 'gt':
                gt("${rule['field']}", rule['value'])
                break;
            case 'ge':
                ge("${rule['field']}", rule['value'])
                break
            case 'lt':
                lt("${rule['field']}", rule['value'])
                break
            case 'le':
                le("${rule['field']}", rule['value'])
                break
            case 'bw':
                ilike("${rule['field']}", "${rule['value']}%")
                break
            case 'bn':
                not{ilike("${rule['field']}", "${rule['value']}%")}
                break
            case 'ew':
                ilike("${rule['field']}", "%${rule['value']}")
                break
            case 'en':
                not{ilike("${rule['field']}", "%${rule['value']}")}
                break
            case 'cn':
                ilike("${rule['field']}", "%${rule['value']}%")
                break
            case 'nc':
                not{ilike("${rule['field']}", "%${rule['value']}%")}
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine and is only a little verbose-looking with the switch statements.  But what if I want to add functionality to choose to match ANY of the rules or ALL of them?  I would need to conditionally put the rules in an `or{}`.  I can't do something like

```
if(groupOp == 'or'){
    or{
}
```

before I go through the rulesList and then

```
if(groupOp == 'or'){
    }
}
```

afterward.  All I can think to do is to repeat the code for each condition:

```
if(groupOp == 'or'){
    or{
        rulesList.each { rule ->
            switch(rule['op']){
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    rulesList.each { rule ->
        switch(rule['op']){
            ...
        }
    }
```

Now the code is looking quite sloppy and repetitive.  Suppose I want to search on a property of a property of the domain object? (Ex: I want to return vehicles whose tires are a certain brand; vehicle.tires.brand, or vehicles whose drivers match a name; vehicle.driver.name).  Would I have to do something like:

```
switch(rule['op']){
    case 'eq':
        switch(thePropertiesProperty){
            case Garage:
                garage{
                    eq("${rule['field']}", rule['value'])
                }
                break
            case Driver:
                driver{
                     eq("${rule['field']}", rule['value'])
                }
                break
        }
        break
    case 'ne':
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, you can simplify your big switch by using a GString for the method name:

```
case ~/^(?:eq|ne|gt|ge|lt|le)$/:
  "${rule['op']}"("${rule['field']}", rule['value'])
  break
```

The same trick works for the and/or:

```
"${(groupOp == 'or') ? 'or' : 'and'}"() {
  rulesList.each { rule ->
    switch(rule['op']){
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

or you could assign the closure to a variable first and then call either `or(theClosure)` or `and(theClosure)` as appropriate.  Finally, for the "property of a property" search, if you add

```
createAlias('driver', 'drv')
createAlias('garage', 'grg')
```

to the top of the criteria closure then you can query on things like `eq('drv.name', 'Fred')` without having to add the intervening `driver {...}` or `garage {...}` node.

Comment: Great solution, it seems I am still not realizing and leveraging the full power of Groovy.  Also, for anyone interested in learning more about createAlias (which I knew nothing about previously) look over [here](http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html)

Comment: Thanks! createAlias solved my problem. I have no idea why it is not mentioned on the createCriteria page of the Grails documentation.